# How to avoid extra single quotation marks

Tags: python, string

How to avoid extra single quotation sign

keywords = "van","buren","william","henry","harrison"

when I print keywords

print keywords

**Output:**

"van","buren","william","henry","harrison"

Nice on console window

When I am using same variable in the query

```
          "fields": ["name","contextType"],
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {    
                    "match": { "contextType": "{}".format(querystring)}
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "content": **["%s" % (keywords)]**
                  } 
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

## Following is the output

**Single Quotation mark automatically add**

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match': {'contextGraph.contextType': 'president'}}, {'terms': {'content': ***['"van","buren","william","henry","harrison"']***
}}]}}}
```

## My Expected Output

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match': {'contextGraph.contextType': 'president'}}, {'terms': {'content': ***["van","buren","william","henry","harrison"]***
}}]}}}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `{'content':keywords[:]}`?

Comment: Thank @Jason, very nice technique

Answer (score 3):

keywords is printing as one large string (enclosed in single quotation marks) because that's what you told it to do:

```
{
    "terms": {
        "content": **["%s" % (keywords)]**
    } 
}
```

If you want keywords to print as a list of individual strings, just print it that way:

```
{
    "terms": {
        "content": keywords
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank @Gordon, I want to print string like "van","buren","william","henry","harrison" this inside the square brackets ["van","buren","william","henry","harrison"]. When I follow your approach to print the string following result has been generated.
{
    "terms": {
        "content": keywords
    } 
}
Result
=====
{
    "terms": {
        "content": \\"van\\",\\"buren\\",\\"william\\",\\"henry\\",\\"harrison\\"
    } 
}

Comment: @SaqibUllah Are you wanting `[ ]` to be part of the string in `content`?